# The screen that layout validation and show system ui is different

Tags: android, user-interface, nox

I made a screen at the Android studio. When I ran it, I couldn't understand that these three screens were different. What should I make the screen according to?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pjuqh.png)

this is show System Ui version

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j7TKE.png)

this is Layout Validation version

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5a2uE.png)

this is Nox version

Answer (score 0):

ImageView has such behavior on some devices, so if your image is a vector type, try by using `app:srcCompat="@drawable/my_image"` instead of `android:src="@drawable/my_image"`.

Answer (score 0):

please share your layout XML code for more clarification on constraints also for the app compact image view, you have to use "app:srcCompat="@drawable/my_image" to load the image. @Whateve